# Submit button to receive postcode

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I am relatively new to this with some JS and PowerShell experience. I am trying to get some code to work where a user would enter their postcode and hit submit, at which point they would be able to pick their address from a list of addresses within that area. All the data from the search would then be saved to a DB under their profile.

I have found this API `http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/` which when you apend the postcode it returns all the relevant information. My question is how do I get either PHP or JS to lookup that address append the inputted postcode and return the address?

```
<body>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <label for="postcodebtn">Enter Postcode:</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Postcode" name="Poscodebtn" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>

    
<script>
     $('#lookup_field').setupPostcodeLookup({
   output_fields: {
     line_1: '#first_line',  
     line_2: '#second_line',         
   line_3: '#third_line',
    post_town: '#post_town',
    postcode: '#postcode'
  }
});


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can use Google API which will give you the list of addresses within that postcode . Or otherwise use JSON / XML format for the same .

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of that JS library you're using and postcodes.io.

Unfortunately, postcodes.io won't get you premise specific data (e.g. houses at a postcode). But it looks like you're using the JS library for [Ideal Postcodes](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk) which can perform that task.

In the snippet you provided, you're looking up a postcode in the browser (on JS). The data from that search should be inserted into `<input>` fields and posted to your PHP server.

However the main issue appears to be you're missing those `<input>`s as well as a `<div>` to accommodate your postcode lookup. Furthermore, this should be wrapped up in a form which can be submitted to your server.

There is a page with a dozen or so demos and code snippets on how to use that library here: [ideal-postcodes.co.uk/jquery](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/jquery). It will demonstrate all the essential elements you need  in order to setup postcode lookup on your website

Good luck!